# Multiple "classes" with same function names

Tags: go, struct

I'm trying to extract some data from myanimelist and imdb using Go. 
The searches is expected to be quite different depending on site that data is collected from therefor a different function (with same name) is needed for myanimelist and imdb. Currently I try to sum my functions in a struct and call upon them through the struct. However this isnt working as expected.

```
type myAnimeList interface {
    search(url string, name string) (string, bool)
    getScore(url string, regex string) (string, bool)
    getTop(url string, regex string) (string, bool)
    getEpisodes(url string, regex string) (string, bool)
    getInfo(url string, regex string) (string, bool)
    getAired(url string, regex string) (string, bool)
}
```

My plan is eventually to use a dictionary like:

```
var SitesAvailable = map[string]interface{}{
    "myanimelist":  http.MyAnimeList,
    "myanimelist2": http.MyAnimeList,
}
```

Were I can decide which search method I want active and call upon them. 
It may look something like:

```
SitesAvailable["myanimelist"].search(url, seriesName)
```

I am quite confused in my thinking and dont have a clear structure on how I can do this. But what I want is a dictionary where I can decide which search method that should be used and some way to separate the imdb functions from myanimelist functions. There must be in the same package.

Any guidance on how I can accomplish this?

## Update 1

So I followed @syazdani example with an common interface and I now have the following. It seem to work as I wanted and improved the structure a bit.

```
type Website interface {
    Search() (string, bool)
    GetScore()
    GetTop() (string, bool)
    GetInfo()
    GetAired()
}

type myAnimeList struct {
    score    string
    rank     string
    episodes string
    info     string
    aired    string
    genre    string
    response string
    url      string
}

func (d myAnimeList) GetSeasonal() (string, bool){
//...
}
func (d myAnimeList) GetTop() (string, bool) {
//...
}
/*(repeat with all functions named in the Website interface)*/

var SitesAvailable = map[string]Website{
    "myanimelist":  http.MyAnimeList,
    "myanimelist2": http.MyAnimeList,
}
```

In order to access the functions call the following:

```
SitesAvailable["myanimelist"].Search(url, name)
```

Since Search takes two arguments of type string that has to be used too.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: There are no classes in Go. These are types.

Comment: Go doesn't have classes. Imagining that it does only leads to confusion.

Comment: What you seem to be describing is two types that satisfy a common interface.

Comment: I followed @syazdani example and will upload what I got so far in a second. I am still a bit confused how to implement this into a dictonary as mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably look into the [Factory pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) to solve this issue. You define an interface (like you have with myAnimeList above, but probably with a more generic name), but then you also need to provide two separate implementations (one for IMDB and another for myAnimeList). I hope that helps!

See [here](https://gobyexample.com/interfaces) for how to implement interfaces in golang.

Comment: The factory pattern is usually a code smell in Go. It exists to solve problems that Go doesn't generally have.

Comment: Your advice of using an interface is completely appropriate, but you should not use a "factory".

Comment: @syazdani Thank you! I updated my post according to your feedback and displayed the solution. :)

Comment: @Flimzy May I ask why factory pattern isnt a appropriate name for it? In my eyes it seem to be the exact idea of the interface in  example given in this answer.

Comment: @Fredrik: Because it's not needed. It only adds complexity to an otherwise simple situation.

Comment: Unless of course your definition/understanding of factory includes simple constructor functions. That can be fine. But in my experience, "factory" usually means something much more complex. Often constructing a different underlying type depending on input parameters.

Comment: @Flimzy So implementing the example given in the link for an interface would not be the same as Factory pattern or do you suggest any better ideas to do it? Would to take time to guide into any example that is implementing it as complex? In my opinion I think it is a great solution for this kind of problem but not sure where the line for it to be complex is marked.

Comment: @Fredrik: I'm sorry, which link are you referring to?

Comment: if there is a choice that needs to be made dynamically between IMDB and myanimelist, then you need a factory method or whatever that does it based on an input. if it can be done statically, then you just need two structs that implement the same interface and are instantiated as needed. I'm not generally aware of a simpler way of doing this dynamically...

Comment: @syazdani: No, of course you don't need a factory method for that. I do that sort of thing _all the time_ in Go, and I never use factory methods.

Comment: @Fredrik: There are no factory methods at that link. There aren't even constructors. Every instance there is instantiated explicitly. i.e. `c := circle{radius: 5}`

Comment: To be honest, the only time I ever see Go code with factory methods, is when I see Go code written by Java and C# developers.

Comment: @Flimzy, now I'm curious.. how do you deal with the dynamic case if you don't use a factory methodin Go? i'm not talking about static where you know what type you need ahead of time...

Comment: @Flimzy I am also curious, perhaps we have different interpretations of a factory method? It's a simple, useful pattern, often just a few lines in a switch block